# If degree of extension is infinite then intermediate ring not need to be a field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

> Let $F\subset K$ be a field extension and $D$ be an intermediate ring such that $F\subset D\subset K$. If $[K:F]$ is infinite then $D$ is not necessary a field.

So basically I need a counter example. I know this is not true if the degree of extension is finite.

Comment: Do you mean $[E:F]$ being infinite? And the first $K$, that should be $E$, right?

Comment: thanks. I just corrected it.. so yes $[K:F]$ should be infinite.

Comment: Henry, if you deem my answer as the right one, please tick it as such, complying with the customs on Mathstackexchange. Thanks.

Comment: of course sure. and thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{Q}[X] \subset \mathbb{Q}(X)$